# How can I create a git repository that contains files from another repository?

Tags: git, github

I have two repositories, A and B.  The file structure of A is:

/scripts
/local-data
etc.

The file structure of B is the same. The difference is that B should be a superset of A.
/scripts 
   all scripts/* from A +
   scripts specific to project B
(i.e. the files from A are on the same directory level as the B-specific scripts)

A is open source on github.  B is proprietary on a server.  Whenever A is updated, the A files in B should also be updated.

How do I set this up?

Comment: Don't Do It.  This is the ghost of Lost Christmases Future speaking to you.   Restructure B to use A as a submodule.

Answer (score 1):

If you currently have 1 repo you should split it into diffrent repos.
Use the `split` command

---

## ***`subtree split`***

> ***`git subtree`***
>    `git-subtree` - **`Merge`** subtrees together or **`split`** repository into subtrees

```
git subtree split -P <name-of-folder> -b <name-of-new-branch>
```

[image]

---

Now create submodule or subtree for your repositories.

First let's explain what is the main difference between subtree and submodule:

both of them are used for having another repo inside existing repo. The main difference is that git `submodule` is independent self-contained repository while `subtree` store the date in the parent (original) repo.

---

### ***`Now let's dig in and explain in  more details:`***

> Is there any simpler example that I can follow?

***`Submodule`*** is a **standalone** git project so the code will be checked out to a **new folder** under the root folder and it's not part of your master branch.

Your root folder will contain a submodule file and you will have to `init && update` it on every clone you make.

```
# Add the desired submodule to your code base
git submodule add <url>
```

You must run two commands:

```
git submodule init
```

to initialize your local configuration file, and

```
git submodule update
```

to fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject:

So the full script is this:

```
git submodule add <url>
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

You simply need to be in your root folder and then add the submodule folder.

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Now when you clone the project you simply need to init and update the submodule

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Git 1.8.2 features a new option --remote

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

will fetch the latest changes from upstream in each submodule, merge them in, and check out the latest revision of the submodule.

[image]

---

## ***`git subtree`***

***Git subtree allows you to insert any repository as a sub-directory of another one***

Very similar to `submodule` but the main difference is where your code is managed. In submodules the content is placed inside a separate repo and is managed there which allow you to clone it to many other repos as well.

***`subtree`*** is managing the content as part of the root project and not in a separate project.

Instead of writing down how to set it up and to understand how to use it you can simply read this excellent post which will explain it all.

https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/